# error: invalid types ‘Pixel*[__complex__ int]’ for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

I'm writing a function that halves an image in both dimensions and memory. The image data is declared in my image object as `Pixel *data`. However, g++ gives me the error below. I find it strange that the error points to [2i*2j] but not [i*j], so it seems that multiplying each index by 2 is what's making the difference somehow.

The function:

```
void HalveInSize(Image &input, Image &output)
{

    output = Image(input.GetX()/2, input.GetY()/2, (Pixel*) malloc(input.GetX()/2 * input.GetY()/2 * sizeof(Pixel)));

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < output.GetX(); i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j < output.GetY(); j++)
        {
                output.GetData()[i*j] = input.GetData()[2i*2j];
        }   
    }
}
```

The compiler error:

```
functions.h: In function ‘void HalveInSize(Image&, Image&)’:
functions.h:65:51: error: invalid types ‘Pixel*[__complex__ int]’ for array subscript
          output.GetData()[i*j] = input.GetData()[2i*2j];
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program? If the `Pixel` class or structure have a constructor it won't be called if you use `malloc`.

Comment: I'm writing this based off of snippets from an existing C program I wrote, but it hasn't caused me any issues so far. But yeah, if it causes any problems, I'll take it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2i` is a `complex` number, the positive squareroot of `-4`. It is nothing to do with your variable `i`. I think you meant `2*i*2*j` (although your loop is not the correct way to iterate over a 2-D array, and you will access outside the bounds that you have malloc'd)

I think you intended

```
for (i = 0; i < output.GetX(); i++)
{
    for (j=0; j < output.GetY(); j++)
    {
            output.GetData()[i * output.GetY() + j] 
               = input.GetData()[2*i*input.GetY() + 2*j];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Argh, too much math stuff on my mind! Thank you -- that fixed it.